# user defined classes in unordered map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm using C++17, MSYS2 MinGW64, OpenGL, stb_image on VScode on Windows. In my code below, I'm trying to recursively search a specific directory for every .png file to load textures (using the Texture object that takes in a std::string parameter). When I run my code, I get these errors:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/tuple: In instantiation of 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {int&&}; long long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0}; _Args2 = {}; long long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = Texture]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/tuple:1678:63:   required from 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {int&&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = Texture]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:150:4:   required from 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, Texture>; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Texture>, false>]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:512:17:   required from 'static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, Texture>; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Texture>, false>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Texture>, false> >]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2037:36:   required from 'std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type* std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::_M_allocate_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = 
{const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _NodeAlloc = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Texture>, false> >; std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Texture>, false> >::value_type]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:272:35:   required from 'std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_Scoped_node::_Scoped_node(std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__hashtable_alloc*, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Value = std::pair<const int, Texture>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Texture> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<int>; _H1 = std::hash<int>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__hashtable_alloc = std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<const int, Texture>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Texture> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::__hashtable_alloc]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:739:42:   required from 'std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::operator[](std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::key_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Pair = std::pair<const int, Texture>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Texture> >; _Equal = std::equal_to<int>; _H1 = std::hash<int>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type = Texture; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::key_type = int]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/unordered_map.h:988:20:   required from 'std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[](std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = Texture; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _Pred = std::equal_to<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Texture> >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Texture; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = int]'
src/GameUI.cpp:32:50:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/tuple:1689:70: error: no matching function for call to 'Texture::Texture()'
 1689 |         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
```

How can I resolve this?

Also, are there any corrections or suggestions that could be made to improve my code (especially the map.emplace bit)?

Code:

```
#include "Texture.h"
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, Texture> map;
    std::string path {"resources\\"};
    std::string ext {".png"};
    size_t count {};

    for (auto &p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
        if (p.path().extension() == ext) {
            map.emplace(count, Texture{p.path().string()}); // Is this the most efficient way?
            std::cout << p.path().string() << std::endl;
        }
            
        else if (!p.is_directory())
            count++;
    }
    Texture test = map[7]; // Line 32 in GameUI.cpp
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string path {"resources/"};` -> `std::string path {"resources\\"};` ?

Comment: All forward slashes should be converted to backslashes by Windows, so I'm not sure that's your problem. Perhaps your working directory isn't what you expect it to be? How do you run your program? Have you tried to use absolute paths?

Comment: Sorry you're right that wasn't the problem. I've adjusted the code a little and now am faced with an error. Does the problem lie in how I'm using the unordered map?

Comment: which is line 32 in GameUI.cpp?

Comment: if your `Texture` has no default constructor, you cannot use the unordered maps `operator[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Texture test = map[7];`

`map[7]` returns a reference on a Texture, or default-constructs it if doesn't exist yet. If Texture doesn't have a default constructor, you get this error.

Try using [map::at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) instead, which throw an exception if `map[7]` doesn't exist. Or `map::find()` if you don't want exceptions. Or, well, just define `Texture::Texture()`...

---

> map.emplace(count, Texture{p.path().string()}); // Is this the most efficient way?

I guess `map.emplace(count, p.path().string())` should be enough, here?